# How to combine multiple .fasta files of primary assembly from Ensembl into one for sequence alignment?

Tags: transcriptome, reference-genome, ensembl, 10x-genomics, cellranger

I have some marmoset snRNA reads that I want to align with the reference transcriptome using cellranger. The primary assembly for marmoset is available here, which is broken down into 22 parts. However, `cellranger mkref` only accepts one `.fa` file to generate the transcriptome.

I tried concatentaing all the extracted `.fa` files into one (After removing the first line which is a comment), but I get the following error while trying to make a reference transcriptome using cellranger:

```bash
Creating new reference folder at /data/users/abhishek/ensembl/common_marmoset_ref/combined/common_marmoset
 ...done
 
 Writing genome FASTA file into reference folder...
 ...done
 
 Indexing genome FASTA file...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/data/public-data/cellranger-6.1.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 137, in <module>
     main()
   File "/data/public-data/cellranger-6.1.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 128, in main
     reference_builder.build_gex_reference()
   File "/data/public-data/cellranger-6.1.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 630, in build_gex_reference
     self.process_fasta()
   File "/data/public-data/cellranger-6.1.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 529, in process_fasta
     subprocess.check_call(["samtools", "faidx", self.fasta_path])
   File "/data/public-data/cellranger-6.1.1/external/anaconda/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['samtools', 'faidx', '/data/users/abhishek/ensembl/common_marmoset_ref/combined/common_marmoset/fasta/genome.fa']' returned non-zero exit     status 1.
```

There are also files which contain only one or two characters. I suspect that these aren't being handled properly with the direct concatenation of all the files. Some examples are below:

```bash
==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.1.fa <==
CCCATTATCCCTGCTTCTGCTAATCTTTCAAAATCTCACCACCATAGTC

==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.20.fa <==
TTTTT

==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.21.fa <==
TT

==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.22.fa <==
AAAATTGTTTCTTGTTT

==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.2.fa <==
C

==> Callithrix_jacchus.mCalJac1.pat.X.dna.primary_assembly.3.fa <==
TTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGG
```

How do I combine all these `.fa` files to generate the reference transcriptome for downstream analysis?

Comment: When you say "After removing the first line which is a comment", do you mean you removed the lines which start with a `>`? Those are the headers and are required to have a valid fasta file. They contain the name or identifier of the contig/chromosome/transcript. They separate the contigs in the fasta if there are multiple and will be needed for alignment in order to know which contigs your reads mapped to.

Comment: Why do not you run "samtools faidx" alone on the fasta file any see if you are getting any useful error message. Looks like your program is calling samtools for indexing. You can tell this from the last line of the error.

Comment: And your fasta file does not look correct.